# how to save a fitted R model for later use

Tags: r

Sorry for this novice question: if I fit a `lm()` model or `loess()` model, and save the model somewhere in a file or in a database, for later use by a third party with `predict()` method, do I have to save the entire model object? Since returned model object contains the original raw data, this returned object can be huge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you include the argument `model = FALSE` (it's true by default) when fitting the model, the model frame that was used will be excluded from the resulting object. You can get an estimate of the memory that is being used to store the model object giving:

```
object.size(my_model)
```