# Is there a way to 'compress' an lm() object for later prediction?

Tags: r, memory, compression

Is there a way to 'compress' an object of class lm, so that I can save it to the disk and load it up later for use with predict.lm?

I have an lm object that ends up being ~142mb upon saving, and I have a hard time believing that predict.lm needs all of the original observations / fitted values / residuals etc. to make a linear prediction. Can I remove information so that the saved model is smaller?

I have tried setting some of the variables (fitted.values, residuals, etc.) to NA, but it seems to have no effect on the saved file size.

Comment: Also, in the spirit of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929776/how-to-save-a-fitted-r-model-for-later-use?rq=1) question, I tried setting `model=FALSE` but that had no noticeable effect.

Comment: If big data is causing your problem then `biglm` may be the answer. An object of class `biglm` is smaller than `lm`, and there are other `big data` efficiencies

Comment: Actually the issue isn't the size of the data in memory, it's the speed I was looking for with the predict() function. My script was creating a nightly-updated model that was called via RPy2 to make predictions for end-users. With the 142mb model, it was taking forever to load each request.

Comment: How are the objects saved? I find it hard to believe they have been serialized.

Comment: Just using R's built-in save() function. I would save the lm object  to a variable and save it to disk. Afterwards, RPy2 loads the object in and then makes linear predictions using user input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `biglm` to fit your models, a `biglm` model object is smaller than a lm model object. You can use `predict.biglm` create a function that you can pass the newdata design matrix to, which returns the predicted values.

Another option is to use `saveRDS` to save the files, which appear to be slightly smaller, as they have less overhead, being a single object, not like save which can save multiple objects.

```
 library(biglm)
 m <- lm(log(Volume)~log(Girth)+log(Height), trees)
 mm <- lm(log(Volume)~log(Girth)+log(Height), trees, model = FALSE, x =FALSE, y = FALSE)
 bm <- biglm(log(Volume)~log(Girth)+log(Height), trees)
 pred <- predict(bm, make.function = TRUE)
 save(m, file = 'm.rdata')
 save(mm, file = 'mm.rdata')
 save(bm, file = 'bm.rdata')
 save(pred, file = 'pred.rdata')
 saveRDS(m, file = 'm.rds')
 saveRDS(mm, file = 'mm.rds')
 saveRDS(bm, file = 'bm.rds')
 saveRDS(pred, file = 'pred.rds')

 file.info(paste(rep(c('m','mm','bm','pred'),each=2) ,c('.rdata','.rds'),sep=''))
#             size isdir mode mtime               ctime               atime               exe
#  m.rdata    2806 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:24:23 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  m.rds      2798 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  mm.rdata   2113 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:24:28 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  mm.rds     2102 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  bm.rdata    592 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:24:34 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  bm.rds      583 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  pred.rdata 1007 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:24:40 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
#  pred.rds    995 FALSE  666 2013-03-07 11:29:30 2013-03-07 11:27:30 2013-03-07 11:29:30  no
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things:

1. This question really is a duplicate.
2. In the narrow sense `model=FALSE` as was already answered in another question.
3. In a wider sense, `predict(fit, newdata)` really just does a matrix-vector multiplication so you could save *just the vector of predictions* and multiply it with a matrix.
4. There are alternate fitting functions. Below is an example from `fastLm()` in RcppArmadillo which also happens to be faster.

See below for an illustration.

```
R> library(RcppArmadillo)
Loading required package: Rcpp
R> flm <- fastLm(Volume ~ Girth, data=trees)
R> predict(flm, newdata=trees[1:5,])             ## can predict as with lm()
[1]  5.10315  6.62291  7.63608 16.24803 17.26120
R> object.size(flm)                              ## tiny object size ...
3608 bytes
R> stdlm <- lm(Volume ~ Girth, data=trees)
R> object.size(stdlm)                            ## ... compared to what lm() has
20264 bytes
R> stdlm <- lm(Volume ~ Girth, data=trees, model=FALSE)
R> object.size(stdlm)                            ## ... even when model=FALSE
15424 bytes
R>
```

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I solved my own problem. Using the following:

```
model<-lm(form,data=ct,model=FALSE,x=FALSE,y=FALSE)
```

reduced the size of my model substantially.