# How to store an R model as text?

Tags: r, save, lm

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896265/how-to-minimize-size-of-object-of-class-lm-without-compromising-it-being-passe), but it is not full.

My question is split in 2 :

1. I want to store a "slim" version of an R lm() object as text in a DBMS.
2. I want to be able to produce predictions out of the text object I saved.

By "slim" I mean with just the right amount of data that the predict() function won't fail. I want to store the model becuase learning sometimes takes a lot of time,  for example :

```
lmFull <- lm(Volume~Girth+Height,data=trees)
lmSlim <- lmFull
lmSlim$fitted.values <- lmSlim$qr$qr <- lmSlim$residuals <- lmSlim$model <- lmSlim$effects <- NULL
pred1 <- predict(lmFull,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
pred2 <- predict(lmSlim,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
identical(pred1,pred2)
[1] True
```

What I have done to store as text is take the lmSlim object and deparse it :

```
lmTxt <- deparse(lmSlim)
lmTxt <- paste0(lmTxt,collapse="")
```

Storing this in the the DB is easy, but when I want to reuse it again :

```
lmRst <- eval(parse(text=lmTxt))
class(lmRst)
[1] "lm"
predict(lmRst,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Volume' not found
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue, might be a bit of a workaround but it works :

```
# learning and reducing the size of output
lmFull <- lm(Volume~Girth+Height,data=trees)
lmSlim <- lmFull
lmSlim$fitted.values <- lmSlim$qr$qr <- lmSlim$residuals <- lmSlim$model <- lmSlim$effects <- NULL
pred1 <- predict(lmFull,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
pred2 <- predict(lmSlim,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
identical(pred1,pred2)
[1] TRUE

# deparse and collapse into a string
lmTxt <- deparse(lmSlim)
lmTxt <- paste0(lmTxt,collapse="")

# re-parsing
lmParsed <- eval(parse(text=lmTxt))
lmParsed$call <- lmFull$call
lmParsed$terms <- lmFull$terms
lmParsed
pred3 <- predict(lmParsed,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
identical(pred1,pred3)
[1] FALSE
```

But...

```
sum(abs(pred1 - pred3))
[1] 1.634248e-13
as.numeric(object.size(lmParsed) / object.size(lmFull))
[1] 0.3449477
```

So I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lmTxt <- dput(lmSlim)
lmRst <- eval(lmTxt)
predict(lmRst,newdata=data.frame(Girth=c(1,2,3),Height=c(2,3,4)))
```

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, `dput` does not return a string. So here's another option:

```
save(lmSlim, file='data.txt', ascii=T)
```

The contents of the file are ascii so it should be possible to write them to a database. To later reload just use the `load` command:

```
load('data.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks. But, dput() has the same class as the object it gets. I need to save it as character.

Comment: Right, sorry for that! I edited the answer with another option, please see above.

Comment: dput does yield a text representation of the lm-object. the example above would be more clear with  tmpfile <- tempfile(); dput(lmSlim, tmpfile); 
fitted(dget(tmpfile)); coef(dget(tmpfile)) etc...

Answer (score 0):

Don't store it as text. Try this:

```
lmFull <- lm(Volume~Girth+Height,data=trees)
lmSlim <- lmFull
lmSlim$residuals <- NULL
lmSlim$effects <- NULL
lmSlim$fitted.values <- NULL
lmSlim$model <- NULL
lmSlim$qr$qr <- NULL
predict(lmSlim)
#works
predict(lmSlim, newdata=data.frame(Girth=30, Height=20))
#works

object.size(lmFull)
#22960 bytes
object.size(lmSlim)
#7920 bytes
```

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly, I **need** to store as text in a DB. I know how to assign objects to variables, this is not the issue. I need a way to write "some text" that when I parse it it will be a slim version of a model that I can predict by.

Comment: Well, in principle, for prerdictions you only need the coefficients and the model formula. So, you could write your own `predict` function.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I agree, but I writing my own prediction function will not scale for other types of fitting functions, 2 will never be as efficient as the R built in functions. don't you agree?