# Extract prediction function only from lm() call

Tags: r

I can generate predictions for a fitted linear model by assigning the output of `lm()` to a name, like `fit_lm`, and then use `predict()` with that fit to generate predictions on newdata (see reprex below).

With big regressions, `lm()` objects can become large, as they carry with them the original data with which they were fit, as well as some other potentially large pieces of data.  When I am doing this in an automated fashion over many datasets, the individual `lm` objects can take up a lot of space, and I don't want to carry around the whole `lm` object.  I would like to extract a predictive function from the fit that I can store and use for prediction.  Is there an easy way to just extract/construct from the fit a function that does prediction?  At the very bottom of my reprex in comments is an example of how I envision the code working.

```r
# Do a lm fit
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:9, y = 2 * 1:9 + 3 + rnorm(9, sd = 0.5))
fit <- lm(y ~ x, df)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.0125 -0.1178 -0.1007  0.3780  0.6995 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   2.8519     0.4035   7.068 0.000199 ***
#> x             1.9969     0.0717  27.851 1.98e-08 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.5554 on 7 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9911, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9898 
#> F-statistic: 775.7 on 1 and 7 DF,  p-value: 1.976e-08

# Predict it
predict(fit, data.frame(x = 5:6))
#>        1        2 
#> 12.83658 14.83351

# Like to see that I could extract the fit as a function that could be used:
#
# f <- regressionFunction(fit)
# vector_of_fits <- f(data.frame(x = 5:6))
#
# vector_of_fits would equal: 
#>        1        2 
#> 12.83658 14.83351
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we borrow a function from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896265/how-to-minimize-size-of-object-of-class-lm-without-compromising-it-being-passe) that reduces the size of the `lm` object.

```
clean_model = function(cm) {
  # just in case we forgot to set
  # y=FALSE and model=FALSE
  cm$y = c()
  cm$model = c()

  cm$residuals = c()
  cm$fitted.values = c()
  cm$effects = c()
  cm$qr$qr = c()
  cm$linear.predictors = c()
  cm$weights = c()
  cm$prior.weights = c()
  cm$data = c()

  # also try and avoid some large environments
  attr(cm$terms,".Environment") = c()
  attr(cm$formula,".Environment") = c()

  cm
}
```

Then write a simple wrapper that reduces the model and returns the prediction function:

```
prediction_function <- function(model) {
  stopifnot(inherits(model, 'lm'))
  model <- clean_model(model)
  function (...) predict(model, ...)
}
```

Example:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:9, y = 2 * 1:9 + 3 + rnorm(9, sd = 0.5))
fit <- lm(y ~ x, df)
f <- prediction_function(fit)
f(data.frame(x = 5:6))
```

> ```
>        1        2 
> 12.83658 14.83351
> ```

Check sizes:

```
object.size(fit)
# 16648 bytes

object.size(prediction_function)
# 8608 bytes
```

For this small example we save half the space.

Let's use some larger data:

```
data(diamonds, package = 'ggplot2')

fit2 <- lm(carat ~ price, diamonds)
predict(fit2, data.frame(price = 200))
f2 <- prediction_function(fit2)
f2(data.frame(price = 200))

print(object.size(fit2), units = 'Mb'); 
object.size(f2)
```

Now we go from 13 Mb to 5376 bytes.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!  I looked for some lm-object cleaning posts, didn't see this one...

Comment: This seems, in my experience, to be so common that it would find it's way into the stats package, or a common CRAN package...

Comment: Some alternate packages my provide linear model functions with smaller objects, such as `RcppArmadillo` or `biglm` (that's big data, not big object).

Comment: I did look at biglm, but I got a little skittish when I further googled and saw different results of using biglm and just lm.  I didn't dig deeper on the differences, thought I'd go this route... example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255520/why-do-lm-and-biglm-in-r-give-different-p-values-for-the-same-data

Answer (score 2):

this is an answer using the helpful `broom` package to tidy model output.

```
library(broom)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:9, y = 2 * 1:9 + 3 + rnorm(9, sd = 0.5))
fit <- lm(y ~ x, df)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.0125 -0.1178 -0.1007  0.3780  0.6995 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   2.8519     0.4035   7.068 0.000199 ***
#> x             1.9969     0.0717  27.851 1.98e-08 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.5554 on 7 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9911, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9898 
#> F-statistic: 775.7 on 1 and 7 DF,  p-value: 1.976e-08
predict(fit, data.frame(x = 5:6))
#>        1        2 
#> 12.83658 14.83351

# store model coef in data frame using broom
model_params <- tidy(fit)
model_params
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic      p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)     2.85    0.403       7.07 0.000199    
#> 2 x               2.00    0.0717     27.9  0.0000000198

# create function to predict from model params
predict_from_params <- function(x, model_params){
  model_params[1,]$estimate + x * model_params[2,]$estimate
  }

predict_from_params(df$x, model_params)
#> [1]  4.848859  6.845790  8.842720 10.839651 12.836581 14.833512 16.830442
#> [8] 18.827373 20.824303
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This works exactly with my particular example of a one-factor regression.  I'm accepting the other one because it generalizes to more than that.  Thanks again!