# R Function to slice a vector/matrix in a rolling manner

Tags: r, zoo, sliding-window

I have once seen this function but can't remember its name now. The function performs a rolling-slice of the input vector/matrix and outputs a matrix with 1 dimension higher. Here is what the function does:

```
rolling_slice <- function(v,window){
  rows = length(v)-window+1
  m <- matrix(0,rows,window)
  for(i in 1:rows){m[i,] <- v[i:(i+window-1)]}
  return(m)
}
```

A sample output with a vector input looks like this:

```
> v <- 1:10
> rolling_slice(v,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    8    9   10
```

The reason to try finding it is I want to speed up the rolling-window operations in R and I hope this function could help by pre-indexing the input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered the base `R` function `embed` and now it is one of my favorite things:

```
> numcol <- 3
> embed(1:10, numcol)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    4    3    2
[3,]    5    4    3
[4,]    6    5    4
[5,]    7    6    5
[6,]    8    7    6
[7,]    9    8    7
[8,]   10    9    8
```

It basically does exactly what you describe by making a matrix of rolling windows of your data, with the second input being the window size.  If order matters you can reverse the columns using:

```
embed(1:10, numcol)[ , numcol:1]
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the function I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `zoo:rollapply/rapply()` or `roll*()` are what you need.
What is your actual end-application: rolling-means, medians, weighted sum, filter, rolling-stdev, something else? I doubt that your end-application is simply taking a sliding-window slice. There's no point in generating huge unnecessary temporary data structure as it'll kill memory and performance.

Also, for performance, this sounds like a case where `data.table`'s sequential access will beat dplyr/tibbles/tidyverse. What data structure are you using?

Comment: I need to perform some rolling correlation/regression on a bunch of time series, potentially with different rolling window. And I want to do them fast. I have been using data.tables and I love it. But it doesn't seem to have a fast rolling apply function

Comment: @Bill: Presumably you turn on the JIT, also profiling, and maybe hardcode `lm` for your case, it's got some flab in it. It helps if you tell us what are input vector/matrix-size N, number of columns C, and window-size W. I sincerely doubt you want to store N complete models, only their coeffts.

Comment: @Bill: other users are using `rollapply` with `data.table`, if you find the performance is bad please post actual numbers and tagged/titled data.frame. Also, if you're generating lots of models, store them as `biglm` rather than `lm` [Is there a way to 'compress' an lm() class for later prediction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260429/is-there-a-way-to-compress-an-lm-class-for-later-prediction/15260950#15260950)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this vectorized in base R:

```
window <- 3
m <- diag(length(v)-window+1)
(row(m)+col(m)-1)[,1:window]

    # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    2    3    4
# [3,]    3    4    5
# [4,]    4    5    6
# [5,]    5    6    7
# [6,]    6    7    8
# [7,]    7    8    9
# [8,]    8    9   10
```